# Dart, how to unit test with zones?

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, dart

I want to test a pathway that sends events through multiple asynchronous `Stream`s, and what I would like to test is that by sending an invalid parameter through the `Stream`s I get a specific type of error thrown at the end but I wasn't sure how to do this, but having looked at Zones it looks like they may offer some hope, [here](https://github.com/0xor1/purity/blob/dev/test/unit/end_to_end.dart#L34) is my failing test, to run the tests just run the `test/unit/start.dart` file. The odd thing is that the complex asynchronous pathway running in the `Zone` does throw the expected error type and so should pass. To test this I tried changing the test to a much simpler version, if you copy paste in the below code over the failing test, this version passes:

```dart
test('A Source may not have #emitEvent invoked on it', (){
  var error;
  expectAsyncWithReadyCheckAndTimeout(
    () => error != null,
    (){
      expect(error == 'hi', equals(true));
    });

  runZoned(
    (){
      executeWhenReadyOrTimeout(() => currentTestConsumer != null, (){ new Future((){}).then((_){ throw 'hi'; });});
    },
    onError: (e){
      error = e;
    });
});
```

I can't figure out why the proper version fails to have its error caught by the zones onError handler and why the simplified version works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this was to appreciate where the error is coming from and that it isn't the fact that the complex async pathway that ultimately leads to the error being thrown is kicked off in the zone in my unit test, but that all the components that make up the complex async pathway like **objects**/**streams**/**futures**/etc are all created ahead of time in the test **setUp**  method, this seems to particularly matter to the **streams**. The key to make this work is to run the statements in the **setUp** method inside a **runZoned** body and handle errors from there, alternatively I could make the **setUp** method something which is called explicitly at the start of each unit test so I could explicitly call the whole **setUp** method inside a **runZoned** body.

Either way, as a code example of how I managed to get it to work it's probably most illustrative to show the experimental code I used to figure out why it wasn't working, though this is essentially exactly what is happening in my libraries test code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

void main(){

  test('This will fail', (){
    var error;

    Timer.run(expectAsync((){
      expect(error, equals('anError'));
    }));

    //create the stream and controller outside the zone
    var controller = new StreamController<String>();
    var stream = controller.stream.asBroadcastStream();
    stream.listen((_){ throw 'anError'; });

    runZoned((){
      //kick off the async pathway to throw the error
      controller.add('');
    }, onError: (e){
      error = e;
    });
  });


  test('This will pass', (){
    var error;

    Timer.run(expectAsync((){
      expect(error, equals('anError'));
    }));

    runZoned((){
      //create the stream and controller inside the zone
      var controller = new StreamController<String>();
      var stream = controller.stream.asBroadcastStream();
      stream.listen((_){ throw 'anError'; });
      //kick off the async pathway to throw the error
      controller.add('');
    }, onError: (e){
      error = e;
    });
  });

}
```